# Genome interval intersection: return only the most overlapping query

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am working with some genomic data and I would like to intersect a gtf exon file with a bed file, but only return the most overlapping feature. There are quite a lot of tools to do intersections, but I haven't found one that gives the exact output I want: 
for each gene in the gtf file which overlaps an interval in the bed file return one bed interval which has the maximum overlap.

I think GenomicRanges::findOverlaps from Bioconductor is a good solution, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to do it. Something like:

```
output <- findOverlaps(query.gtf, subject.bed, minoverlap=10, ignore.strand=F)
```

Followed by something along the lines of:

```
aggregate(output[transcript_id_field], list(#bp_field), max)
```

If there is not a simple solution I am prepared to write a script to extract this information from a full intersection file, but putting this problem out there I'm hoping someone might have a more efficient solution.